# rails, form_for in a secon route, but on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In a rails 4 application, I have a book resource, that is a Book model with its controller, views and route. It's what gets created by:

```
rails g scaffold book title
```

Now I want to have another set of views (and another controller) that allows to manage the same model, maybe dedicated to a different user. 
I want both the creating function and the editing function to be available on this different route and view, . 
Let's call it book2. 
The views in the /book2 url should operate on the Book2sController.

#### form_for support

But the `form_for` guesses the submit route (and puts it in the action attribute) from the model class, that, being it always Book, lets rails guess that the submit url is /books/1 for edit or /books/ for new and not /book2s/1 for edit and /book2s/ for new as it should be. 
So i found this solution, but i find it to be a bit cumbersome. 
Is there anything better out there?

```
<%= form_for @book, :url => @book.new_record? ? url_for(book2s_path) :   url_for(book2_path(@book))  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the url in your controller.

```
def new
  # ...
  @form_url = book2s_path
  # ...
end

def edit
  # ...
  @form_url = book2_path(@book)
  # ...
end
```

Then your view becomes:

```
<%= form_for @book, :url => @form_url  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

I have also seen:

```
<%= form_for @book, :url => {:controller => 'book2s', :action => @action}  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

and you just set `@action` in the controller (probably `create` or `update`).

Note that you don't need to include the `url_for` like you have.